# React - use the exact same component instance many times in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I have a React component that's a div, some styling, and text. That exact component with the exact same value is used many, many times in the DOM. I am trying to figure out how to create just one instance of that component, and simply present the exact same instance everywhere that I need it. I tried use memoization, but that seems to be memoizing the instance itself.

Just to be explicitly clear, I'd like to memoize the component such that calling the function with the same arguments from anywhere will return the exact same instance every single time.

```
const Component = React.memo((value) => (<div>...</div>));
```

Calling this seems to memoize the particular *instance*, but it will *still create a brand new instance every single time it's invoked from a different place in the Virtual DOM*, even if the arguments are identical. As I understand it, React.Memo is just a wrapper around a particular instance.

I've thought of some hacky ways to do this, but wanted to ask before exploring that further.

Comment: That is an explicitly different question. That is saying the same component is rendered many times and is talking about how to synchronize state between all instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

```
const AppContext = React.createContext(null);
            
const App = () => (
  <AppContext.Provider value={...//your component} >
    //...
  </AppContext.Provider>)
)
```

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
  const Component = useContext(AppContext);
  
  return (
    <div>
      //...
      {Component}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. this is one of the ideas i had in mind, but it seems less consumable than i was hoping. Would the value be `value={<Component />}`?

Comment: Yes, that way you can persist the same Component instance. I don't know how is your component, is just an idea ;)

Comment: Thank you! I’ll brainstorm on it. Was hoping there’d be a better API for something like this.

Comment: I wasn't thinking this through before. `<Component />` is really just a function reference that React executes to get the current state. Which means that this is just an indirect way of importing the function for react to render in the consumers.

Comment: Tomorrow, I'll probably look at using lodash to memoize. Will write back if that seems to work fine.

Comment: OK, let me know :)

Comment: So it seems to be hacky, but it works if you memoize a functional component using Lodash. A caveat is it probably only works for a component that takes no props. By setting the memoize functions second param to a constant `()=>1`, I was able to verify that I only ever get one particular instance back. However, I haven’t done extensive testing with this. My hunch is this will help with memory management when components are repeated often - in my case, an infinite scroll grid with many identical cells.

Comment: Nice, ;). I think the Context is a good solution, it is native, and you don't need an extra libs. If you want to update some props, in the context component you can have a callback function, something like this: value={component: <Component {...props}/>, setProps}, and setProps update that properties.

Comment: I tried the context api as well, and it actually doesn’t work well unless you also use something like Lodash because in your example, component is really just a function. Any consumers of this will separately execute the function, thus it’s actually not a singleton but many separate instances.

Comment: Giving an update here. React's 'on road' strategy is to re-render, always. I wound up using the flyweight pattern to share my state objects using a custom solution. However, for sharing/recycling React components, I did not bother trying to do anything like this with the actual React nodes because it seems like it could break easily with future React version upgrades.